# How do I use linq projection and project into a sub collection on the root projected object?

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to do this....

```
var entity = landingPages.Select(x = new MyClass { name = x.name, age = x.age });
```

The only problem is that age is actually a coolection so I thought I would do this...

```
var entity = landingPages.Select(x = new MyClass { name = x.name, age.add(x.age) });
```

But it dont work. Is this possible?

Comment: whats the reason why it does not work?

Comment: because you cant do age.add(x), or can you? thats my question....

Comment: I mean: What is the compile/run time error you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var entity = landingPages.Select(x => new MyClass
{  //this is an initialization block.  Only Property Assignment is allowed.
  name = x.name,
  age.add(x.age)  //arbitrary statements are not allowed in initialization blocks.
});
```

---

You didn't say which age was a collection (LandingPage's age or MyClass' age).

If it's the LandingPage's age, then: convert the single value into a collection.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> query = landingPages.Select(x => new MyClass
{
  name = x.name,
  age = new List<int>() { x.age } //this is a collection initializer
});
```

If it's MyClass' age, then: convert the collection to a single value.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> query = landingPages.Select(x => new MyClass
{
  name = x.name,
  age = x.age.Sum()
});
```